# Q: Bug on Form and TextField [SwiftUI]

Tags: ios, forms, swiftui, textfield

When I use `TextField` in `Form`, the correct value is not displayed until tap the field.

The name field is initially displayed `dummy` and change to `shuji` when tapped.

If I change `Form` to `VStack`, initial value is displayed.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct User {
    var name: String
    var email: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var user: User
    @State private var name: String = "dummy"
    @State private var email: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit user")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Save") {
                    user.name = name
                    user.email = email
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            name = user.name
            email = user.email
        }
    }
}
```

**FormTestApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FormTestApp: App {
    @State var user = User(name: "shuji", email: "shuji@abc.com")
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(user: $user)
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on iPhone 12 iOS 15.1, and Simulator iOS 15.0

Comment: I wonder was this working in iOS 14.x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "make it work", move the `.onAppear {...}` to just after a `TextField`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var user: User
    @State private var name: String = "dummy"
    @State private var email: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .onAppear {   // <--- here
                        name = user.name
                        email = user.email
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit user")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Save") {
                    user.name = name
                    user.email = email
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue in iOS 15 and this actually worked. Thanks!